# Cannot build Qt 6.5.0

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

Why can't I build Qt 6.5.0? I need 6.5.0 because 6.5.1 messes up my project and they removed 6.5.0 from the maintenance tool. I have everything installed. But running configure.bat says some file is missing.
I have:

- CMake 3.26.4
- GCC 12 from winlibs
- Tiny11

The Error is:

```
-- Configuring submodule 'qthttpserver'
-- Configuring submodule 'qttools'
CMake Error at C:/MinGW/lib/cmake/llvm/LLVMExports.cmake:677 (message):
The imported target "LLVMDemangle" references the file 

   "C:/MinGW/lib/libLLVMDemangle.dll.a"

but this file does not exist. Possible reasons include:

* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
  "C:/MinGW/lib/cmake/llvm/LLVMExports.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/MinGW/lib/cmake/llvm/LLVMConfig.cmake:267 (include)
  C:/MinGW/lib/cmake/clang/ClangConfig.cmake:10 (find_package)
  qttools/cmake/FindWrapLibClang.cmake:17 (find_package)
  qtbase/cmake/QtFindPackageHelpers.cmake:144 (find_package)
  qttools/configure.cmake:20 (qt_find_package)
  qtbase/cmake/QtFeature.cmake:592 (include)
  qttools/src/CMakeLists.txt:18 (qt_feature_evaluate_features)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
CMake Error at qtbase/cmake/QtProcessConfigureArgs.cmake:994 (message):
CMake exited with code 1.
NativeCommandExitException: Program "configure.bat" ended with non-zero exit code: 1.
```

I tried installing LLVM toolchain for MinGW-w64 from [here](https://github.com/mstorsjo/llvm-mingw). But it didn't work, I also tried installing LLVM using the official installer and It is still installed and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Qt 6.5.1 is supposed to be a patch release. If it messes up your project (and Qt 6.5.0 does not), did you check if your problem are reported in the [Qt bugtracker](https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa)?

Comment: Your problem is not with QT6 itself, but with LLVM installation which is used. The error message describes what exactly is wrong with that installation and possible reasons. Since we don't know how exactly you have installed LLVM (and whether you have moved or removed any file after that installation), then **only you** could evaluate these possible reasons.

Comment: If you want us to help you with installing LLVM on MinGW, then you need provide **more information** about that problem. Simple "I installed from <link> and it doesn't work" is not sufficient.

Comment: Using msys2 to install MinGW is probably a better option. Although with that said I have not tested building Qt6 from source using it.

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful: [link](https://github.com/brechtsanders/winlibs_mingw/issues/2#issuecomment-997625712)

Comment: Currently going through the same issue with 6.6.2 and yes I am aware of the installer.

Comment: Made a [post](https://forum.qt.io/topic/155248/failing-to-build-qt-6-6-2-from-source-on-windows-10-with-mingw64-compiler) on the Qt forums

Answer (score 0):

You can see older releases in *Maintenance Tool* by selecting `Archive` checkbox on the right side and clicking `Filter` button.

[image]